# Why is the coefficient of a fraction $\frac{1}{denominator}$ instead of simply 1?

Tags: fractions

Why is the coefficient of a fraction $\frac{1}{denominator}$ instead of simply $1$?

Wouldn't the result be the same?

Comment: The context is not clear. Are you referring to coefficients in polynomials? e.g. writing $\frac{1}{4}x^2$ vs. $\frac{x^2}{4}$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "coefficient of a fraction"? Could you provide more context?

Answer (score -1):

Depends of where you are taking the coefficients. For example Q is generated by 1, taking the coefficients in Q, but if you take them in Z you get just the integers and not all rationals. This becomes clearer when one studies modules and vector spaces.

Comment: I'm just studying beginning algebra. I'll wait and see, thank you.